# Pandas resampling on same frequency - how to copy rows?

Tags: python, pandas, frequency, data-manipulation, resampling

Please consider the following reproducible dataframe as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

list_dates = ['2018-01-05',
              '2019-01-01',
              '2019-01-02',
              '2019-01-05',
              '2019-01-08',
              '2019-01-22']

index = []
for i in list_dates:
    tp = datetime.strptime(i, "%Y-%m-%d")
    index.append(tp)

data = np.array([np.arange(6)]*3).T
columns = ['A','B', 'C']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = index, columns=columns)
df['D']= ['Loc1', 'Loc1', 'Loc2', 'Loc2', 'Loc4', 'Loc3']
df['E'] = [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]
```

Image of the above example dataframe:

[image]

Then, I try to create a new dataframe `df2` by resampling the above dataset, so I have all daily dates between 2018-01-05 (first date in `list_dates`) and 2019-01-22 (last date in `list_dates`). When doing the resampling, I basically create new rows in my dataframe for which I don't have any data.

These new rows should simply be copies of their last known value. So for example, in my example dataframe above, I have data for 2018-01-05, but not for 2018-01-06 until 2018-12-31. All these rows should be filled with the values of the previous / last known value (= the row of 2018-01-05).

I tried doing that using:

```
df2 = df.resample('D').last()
```

However, this doesn't work. Instead I get the full range of dates from 2018-01-05 until 2019-01-22, where all new rows (that were not in the original dataframe `df`) have `nan` values only.

What am I missing? Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: Will the new dataframe be at the same length of the original df? And will just have the values of the original df be labeled as the date after the dates from the original?

Comment: No, it will be longer. The original df has 6 rows, whereas the new one has 383 as it creates new rows for all the dates between 2018-01-05 and 2019-01-22. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Basically, the rows and their values that you see in the image, should be copied to the new rows. So, the new row should just be a complete copy of the previous / last known value, except that the index is of course a different date.

Comment: Who would take the values from the first df? The dates that have `date from df2 - date from df` ? and all else would be NAN values?

Comment: Apologies, I'm just trying to understand the question. From the way I see it, you can just create a list of all the dates within the range you want. Then iteratively placing values in other columns based on that list. Once done, your DataFrame should have  been populated by either `Nan` or `values from your first df`.

Comment: Nothing should be NAN. All newly created rows should be copies of one of the existing rows of the original `df`. If you run this part: `df2 = df.resample('D').last()` you'll see that `df2` contains 383 - 6 = 377 rows with NAN values. These should however be filled with the values of the original (6) rows, according to the rule I described earlier (i.e. just a copy of the last known value / row).

Comment: I understand what you mean by your last comment, but my real dataset (not shown here) contains millions of rows. So I was hoping it would work via the `resample` method. The method already creates all the dates I need (i.e. all dates between a min and max), but now all I need is not have NANs, but have copied values of previous rows.

Comment: My bad, I was using `df2 = df.resample('D').last()` where I should have used `df2 = df.resample('D').ffill()`. Once I have a complete solution, I will provide a clear answer to my own question. Thanks for your help